# Regular Expression to match few characters from a string

Tags: regex, string, algorithm

I am trying to find a string within another string. However, I am trying to match even if one or more character is not matching.

Let me explain with an example :

Let's say I have a string **'abcdefghij'**. Now if the string to match is **'abcd'**,

I could write strfind('abcdefghij', 'abc')

Now, I have a string 'adcf'. Notice that, there is a mismatch in two characters, I would consider it as a match.

Any idea how to do it ?

I know, this is not the most optimal code.

Example :

```
a='abcdefghijk';
b='xbcx'
c='abxx'
d='axxd'
e='abcx'
f='xabc'
g='axcd'
h='abxd'
i ='abcd'
```

All these strings should match with `a`.  I hope this example makes it more clear. The idea is, if there is a mismatch of 1 or 2 characters also, it should be considered as a match.

Comment: So you want to match atleast one character ?

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like this:

```
A = 'abcdefghij'; % Main string
B = 'adcf'; % String to be found
tolerance = 2; % Maximum number of different characters to tolerate

nA = numel(A);
nB = numel(B);
pos = find(sum(A(mod(cumsum([(1:nA)' ones(nA, nB - 1)], 2) - 1, nA) + 1) == repmat(B, nA, 1), 2) >= nB - tolerance);
```

In this case it will return **pos = [1 3]';** because "**adcf**" can be matched on the first position (matching "**a?c?**") and on the third position (matching "**?d?f**")

**Explanation:**

- First, we take the sizes of A and B
- Then, we create the matrix `[(1:nA)' ones(nA, nB - 1)]`, which gives us this:

Output:

```
 1     1     1     1
 2     1     1     1
 3     1     1     1
 4     1     1     1
 5     1     1     1
 6     1     1     1
 7     1     1     1
 8     1     1     1
 9     1     1     1
10     1     1     1
```

- We perform a cumulative sum to the right, using [cumsum](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html), to achieve this:

Output:

```
 1     2     3     4
 2     3     4     5
 3     4     5     6
 4     5     6     7
 5     6     7     8
 6     7     8     9
 7     8     9    10
 8     9    10    11
 9    10    11    12
10    11    12    13
```

- And use the [mod](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mod.html) function so each number is between 1 and nA, like this:

Output:

```
 1     2     3     4
 2     3     4     5
 3     4     5     6
 4     5     6     7
 5     6     7     8
 6     7     8     9
 7     8     9    10
 8     9    10     1
 9    10     1     2
10     1     2     3
```

- We then use that matrix as an index for the A matrix.

Output:

```
abcd
bcde
cdef
defg
efgh
fghi
ghij
hija
ijab
jabc
```

Note this matrix has all possible substrings of A with size nB.

- Now we use [repmat](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) to replicate B down, 'nA rows'.

Output:

```
adcf
adcf
adcf
adcf
adcf
adcf
adcf
adcf
adcf
adcf
```

- And perform a direct comparison:

Output:

```
 1     0     1     0
 0     0     0     0
 0     1     0     1
 0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0
```

- Summing to the right give us this:

Output:

```
2
0
2
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

Which are the number of character matches on each possible substring.

- To finish, we use [find](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) to select the indexes of the matches within our tolerance.

Comment: Glad you liked it. I've added a step by step explanation of how I came to this solution, hope it's useful.

Answer (score 1):

In your code

`c=a-b` is not valid (Matrix dimensions not same)

If you need at least one match, not in order, (as your example says), you can have something like this :-

```
>> a='abcdefgh';
>> b='adcf';
>> sum(ismember(a,b)) ~= 0

ans =

     1
```

Comment: @POW, I am not sure, if it works under all condition. I am trying to find the occurrence of a match in another string ( including if one of the character is mismatch). However, your solution would result in a match, even if the characters are not in order and even if one of the character is matching.

Comment: @www.sapnaedu.in Sorry I'm not getting of your "order" in this context. In fact your `adcf` is not in order, correct order should be `acdf` Could you give an example please ?

Comment: @www.sapnaedu.in and all your edited post's test strings matches with `a` with my solution, isn't it ?

Comment: @POW, Definitely it does, however, its too broadbased. It does not take the order of characters into consideration. Suppose a='abcdef' and b='xaaa'. It still gives a match which is not correct.